# Взломали сайт на Bitrix

Tags: битрикс, взлом

Может кто сталкивался с подобным на сайт добавилось множество файлов
[image: Скрин с добавленными файлами]

Всё восстановил через гит, но файл index.php не откатывается, если его удалить, он сам по себе восстанавливается, была задача в агенте, удалил ее, в кроне вроде всё тоже чисто.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такими делами?)

Answer (score 1):

Перезапустить сервер. Откатывать index перестанет. Проверить на вирусы. Удалить очевидно зараженные файлы. Потом перезапустить сервер еще раз, т.к. этот вирус запускает скрипт, который создает кривые файлы. Опять проверить и удалить. Повторять до тез пор пока все не удалите.
Еще htaccess-ы удалить. Но они как правило в каждой папке создаются. Вручнуб удалять долго. Поэтому проще написать скрипт небольшой который удалит их, т.к содержимое везде одинакове